# Inject Script Block after SP.js loads

Tags: development, javascript

I have a giant script block inside my code file and I want to load it after SP.js loads.  I've looked at ScriptLink, but I don't think ScriptLink injects code, it only injects code files.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

PS: In case you're wondering why I have the JS file in my code: its because I have to update the JS file depending on some settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function and inject your Javascript like this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
    //insert your JS stuff here
}, 'sp.js');
```

This way the code in the anonymous function will be executed when sp.js is loaded.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, but I get this error: unterminated string literal.  I have the following code inside the function -> $('head').append("big, neat javascript");.

I have double checked everything and the script is perfect, I'm guessing it might be related to javascript?  The script is huge.

Comment: You got something wrong with your JavaScript most likely. And, please consider a redesign; set a number of variables in the dynamically injected JS and use a normal JS file with the logic

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I totally did a redesign of my plan and came up with a better design. I just created a global variable from code behind, and put unique values in it so I can do my craziness.  Thanks for that advice!